# nuget restore cannot resolve package from Azure DevOps feed via Upstream

Tags: feed, nuget-package-restore, azure-devops-server-2019

I have the following setup:

I have an Azure DevOps 2019 Server. I created two feeds. One to push my own NuGet-Packages. And a second one for restoring the packages. The second one has the first feed and NuGet.org defined as upstream source.

Theoretically, when I restore packages via the second Feed, it should download the packages from the upstream feeds. The package then should be added to the second feed.

But for me it sometimes works but sometimes it doesn't work.

I searched for information in the Microsoft documentation, but didn't find anything regarding this problem. Has anyone experience with such setup?